# Compute matrix integral $\int_0^1 ((I-A)+A \operatorname{diag}(a)t)^{-1}v \cdot a \,dt$

Tags: matrix-calculus, line-integrals, matrix-exponential

How to perform the following line integral
\begin{align}
\int_0^1  ((I-A)+A \operatorname{diag}(r(t)))^{-1}v \cdot r'(t) \, dt
\end{align}
where $r(t)= a t$ with $a \in \mathbb{R}^n$, and where `$\cdot$' denotes dot product.

Also, lets assume that there are no issues with inversion.

**What I did**
The first thing I did is to simplify the expression

$$
\int_0^1  ((I-A)+A \operatorname{diag}(a)t)^{-1}v \cdot a \, dt
$$

My intuition from one dimension case tells me that we should get an expression with a logarithm. However, I am not sure how to go about this in the matrix case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define the matrices
$$\eqalign{
&B = (I-A),\quad &C = B^{-1}A\;{\rm Diag}(a) \\
&(I-A)+A{\,\rm Diag}(a)&t = B\,(I+Ct) \\
}$$
Assume that $\lim_{n\to\infty}C^n=0\,$ and perform the integration term-by-term over a series. 
$$\eqalign{
J &= \int_0^1 a^T\Big((I-A)+A{\,\rm Diag}(a)\,t\Big)^{-1}v\,dt \\
  &= a^T\Bigg(\int_0^1 (I+Ct)^{-1}dt\Bigg)B^{-1}v \\
  &= a^T\Bigg(\int_0^1 \big(I-Ct+C^2t^2-C^3t^3+\ldots\big)\,dt\Bigg)B^{-1}v \\
  &= a^T\Big(I-\tfrac{1}{2}C+\tfrac{1}{3}C^2-\tfrac{1}{4}C^3+\ldots\Big)\,B^{-1}v \\
  &= a^T\Big(C^{-1}\log(\,I+C\,)\Big)\,B^{-1}v \\
}$$
If $\,\Big(C^{-1}\log(\,I+C\,)\Big)\,$ exists and is real-valued, then this result remains valid, even if the assumed limit isn't zero. If none of these conditions are satisfied, you still might be able to perform the integration via numerical quadrature.

Comment: Thanks. A few questions  1)  the integral $\int (I+Ct) dt$ is it defined cell-wise? 2) $\log(I+C)$ this is a matrix logarithm, right?

Comment: Integration (and differentiation) is _always_ an element-wise process -- there's no other way to define it. In the case of multiplication or function application, one usually assumes element-wise operations for rectangular matrices (and vectors) -- again there's no other way to do it. Only in the case of _square_ matrices is there an ambiguity. That being said, the inverse and logarithm functions in my post are applied matrix-wise, and are equal to the power series immediately above it.

Comment: Thanks. One more question how do you define $C^n$? Is it  $C \times C \times ... \times C$ n times?

Comment: Yes, $C^n$ is just the usual matrix product of $C$ with itself $n$ times.